# macOS Ventura 13.2+ Login Items removed on start up

Tags: login, ventura, login-items

I have downloaded the app [Magnet](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12) and added it to my Login Items under *System Settings → General → Login Items*. When I login / logout from lock there is no problem. When I restart my computer, however, I get a warning that Magnet has been added to Login Items and runs tasks in the background. When I go back to *System Settings → General → Login Items*,  I see that Magnet is no longer there.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Might not work, as I don't have this issue, but often times using Disk Utility to "repair" permissions fixes these kinds of issues. It's now called "First Aid" in Disk Utility. I wouldn't mess around with third-party apps that promise to do fix this. Stay away from those.